# Finding closest tree in LiDAR data with respect to electricity line?

Tags: qgis, postgis, lidar

I have a LiDAR point cloud. [image: This is an example of my LiDAR project]

As you see I have one electricity line. I want to vectorise it and then I want to find the closest tree point to electricity line. How can I achieve?

I am open to all programmes and algorithms.

I thought to create a circle and create a cylinder along the line but it is useless too...

Comment: welcome to GIS SE. Do you have a classification/label that tells you which are the points that belong to the power line ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I dont have classification level but I can imagine; I can not solve without making classification

Comment: If you are "open to all programmes and algorithms" it sounds like you are seeking a software recommendation so the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange may be the place to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

With CloudCompare.

You can do a C2C distance (Cloud to Cloud distance) between your point cloud and your wires (your reference), and you will looking the nearest points of your wires.

For optimize the compute, you also can put a maximum distance. By example, if you put a maximal distance 5, all the object who are further from 5 are not computed.